# PHP String compare with Wildcard

Tags: php

I thought this would be really easy but I can't find a simple solution, I really like PHP but only know the basics.

I'm after a simple something so that I can find:

```
http://www.myurl.com/*
```

So just the my url followed by wildcard.  So it would return:

```
 http://www.myurl.com/page1.php
 http://www.myurl.com/page2.php
 http://www.myurl.com/page3.php
```

but not

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Is regex the way to go or is it overkill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a `startsWith` function would work well.

```
<?php
function startsWith($haystack, $needle, $caseInsensitive = false) {
    // if doing case-insensitive
    if ($caseInsensitive){
        return (strcasecmp(substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)), $needle) === 0);
    }
    return (strcmp(substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)), $needle) === 0);
}
```

You can use it like:

```
startsWith('http://www.myurl.com/page1.php', 'http://www.myurl.com/', true);
```

Comment: You could also use [`parse_url`](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) but I have a feeling it would be just as slow or slower than regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for this, lovely code. PHP is a lovely lanuage when seen like this.